# Induced map between a space and an Eilenberg Maclane space

Tags: algebraic-topology, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

Why does there exist a map $X\rightarrow K(H_i(X;\mathbb Q),i)$    corresponding by the universal coefficient theorem to  $H_i(X;\mathbb Z)\rightarrow H_i(X;\mathbb Q)$    induced from the inclusion  $\mathbb Z\rightarrow \mathbb Q$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a map (up to homotopy) $X \to K(H_i(X; \mathbb{Q}), i)$ corresponds to giving a cohomology class in degree $i$ of $X$ with $H_i(X; \mathbb{Q})$-coefficients (if $X$ is nice). The identity map $H_i(X; \mathbb{Q}) \to H_i(X; \mathbb{Q})$ leads by dualization to a natural cohomology class of $H^i(X; H_i(X; \mathbb{Q}))$. (Since we're over a field, the Ext term in the universal coefficient theorem doesn't do anything.)